# How to make each turtle takes different random values for a variable?

Tags: netlogo

If you run this code:

```
globals [ var ]

to setup

  ca
  create-turtles 10
  [
    set var random 10
  ]

  reset-ticks

end
```

and then you make list of the `var` variable of the 10 turtles (using `show (list [var] of turtles` ), the list will contain 10 same values, for example `[ 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ]`. It seems that the `set var random 10` procedure assigns one same value to that `var` variable for all turtles.

What code should I type so each turtle takes `random 10` value that relatively different from each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined `var` as a global, a variable shared by all the turtles. Its value, therefore, will be the value returned by `random 10` for the last turtle created, overwriting all the values returned by the previously created turtles.  You want var to be a `turtles-own` variable with a separate value associated with (owned by) each turtle.

Try this:

```
turtles-own [ var ]

to setup
  ca
  create-turtles 10
  [
    set var random 10
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Each turtle will report its own value of var, rather that the value shared by them all when it was declared a global.

Comment: Oh! Now I understand when we have to assign a variable to global or _agents_-own. That totally works! Thanks, Charles.